# Setting a value inside an array designated by a named property

Tags: php

If I have the following code:

```
$a = new stdClass();
$property = 'test';

$a->$property = array();
```

How can I set a value inside the `$a->$property` array? The following doesn't work, because `[]` is applied on `$property`, not on `$a->$property`:

```
$a->$property['key'] = 'value';
```

Is referencing the property the only way of doing this?

```
$array = &$a->$property;
$array['key'] = 'value';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference it as `$a->{$property}['key'] = 'value';`.